# Problem in Rick Miranda - check that map is unramified

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, ramification

Let $U$ be the affine curve defined by $x^2=3+10t^4+3t^8$ and $V$ the curve defined by $w^2=z^6-1$. Both are smooth.

Let $F:U\to V$ be defined by $(x,y)\mapsto (z,w)= (\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2},\frac{2tx}{(1-t^2)^3})$.

The exercise is to check that $F$ is unramified when $t\neq\pm 1$.

Now, however I try to do it, I get very complicated computations. For example in generic points (where the right hand side of each equation is non zero), respectively $t,z$ are coordinates for $U,V$. So writing $F$ in these local coordinates we have $z=\frac{2tx}{(1-t^2)^3}=\frac{2t\sqrt{3+10t^4+3t^8}}{(1-t^2)^3}$, but I just can't write down the roots of the derivative of this function, its too much computation.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem in a computationally possible way? I realize that $U$ is of genus 3 and $V$ is of genus 2 by furthur materiel or the preceeding exercise in the book. Thus Huruwitz's formula says that degree of $F$ is at most 2 and in that case F is unramified. Also the preimage of $(0,i)$ is of size 2. So this basically proves F is unramified even in the projective closure. However, I am looking for a more elementary solution with not (too) much computation, if its possible.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you mixed up the formulas for $z$ and $w$. According to your definition of $F$ you have $z = \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$ involving only the parameter $t$, so you should be able to just take a derivative, at least for points where $z^6 - 1 \neq 0$ and $3+10t^4+3t^8 \neq 0$.

Comment: I am also confused by this problem. In the local coordinates $t$ on $U$ and $z$ on $V$, the map $F$ is represented by a holomorphic function (away from $t=\pm 1$) $t\mapsto z(t)=(1+t^2)/(1-t^2)$. The derivative of this gives $z'(t)=4t/(1-t^2)^2$. Therefore, at $t=0$, it has multiplicity $+2$ and hence ramified. What is the catch? (I think what you wrote is in the local coordinates $t$ on $U$ and $w$ on $V$, right?)